# Visibility of other transactions inside given one

Tags: postgresql, visibility, isolation-level, mvcc

How does Postgres decide which transactions are visible to a given transaction according to the isolation level?

I know that Postgres uses `xmin` and `xmax` and compares it to `xid`, but I haven't found the articles with proper details.

Do you know the process under hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the current *snapshot*.

`READ COMMITTED` transactions take a new snapshot for every query, while `REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE` transactions take a snapshot when the first query is run and keep it for the whole duration of the transaction.

The snapshot is defined as `struct SnapshotData` in `include/utils/snapshot.h` and essentially contains the following:

- a minimal transaction ID `xmin`: all older transactions are visible to this snapshot.
- a maximal transaction ID `xmax`: all later transactions are not visible to this snapshot.
- an array of transaction IDs `xid` that contains all in-between transactions that are not visible to this snapshot.

To determine if a tuple is visible to a snapshot, its `xmin` must be a committed transaction ID that is visible and its `xmax` must not be a committed transaction ID that is visible.

To determine if a transaction is committed or not, the *commit log* has to be consulted unless the *hint bits* of the tuple (which cache that information) have already been set.